# Executing a process on IIS makes RAM goes up really quick

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, memory-management

I built an ASP.NET MVC API hosted on IIS on Windows 10 Pro (VM on Azure - 4GB RAM, 2CPU). Within I call an .exe ([wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)) that I want to convert an HTML page to image and save it locally. Everything works fine, except I noticed that after some calls to the API, the RAM goes crazy and while investigating the process with Task Manager I saw a process, called IIS Worker Process, that adds more RAM every time the API is called. Of course I wrapped my System.Diagnostics.Process instance usage inside a using statement to be disposed, because IDisposable is implemented, but it still consumes more and more RAM and after a while the server becomes laggy and unresponsive (it has only 4GB of RAM after all). I noticed that after some number of minutes (10-15-20 maybe) this IIS Worker Process calms down in terms of RAM usage... Here is my code, pretty straight forward:

1. Gets base64 encoded url
2. Decodes it
3. Uses wkhtmltoimage.exe to convert it to image
4. Saves it locally
5. Reads the byte array
6. Creates a blob in Azure with the image
7. Returns json with the url

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string url)
   {
       object oJSON = new { url = string.Empty };

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value: url))
       {
           try
           {
               byte[] EncodedData = Convert.FromBase64String(s: url);
               string DecodedURL = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes: EncodedData);

               using (Process proc = new Process())
               {
                   proc.StartInfo.FileName = wkhtmltopdfExecutablePath;
                   proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"--encoding utf-8 \"{DecodedURL}\" {LocalImageFilePath}";
                   proc.Start();
                   proc.WaitForExit();

                   oJSON = new { procStatusCode = proc.ExitCode };
               }

               if (System.IO.File.Exists(path: LocalImageFilePath))
               {
                   byte[] pngBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path: LocalImageFilePath);

                   System.IO.File.Delete(path: LocalImageFilePath);

                   string ImageURL = await CreateBlob(blobName: $"{BlobName}.png", data: pngBytes);

                   oJSON = new { url = ImageURL };
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(value: ex);
           }
       }

       return Json(data: oJSON, behavior: JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }

   private async Task<string> CreateBlob(string blobName, byte[] data)
   {
       string ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + AzureStorrageAccountName + ";AccountKey=" + AzureStorageAccessKey + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
       CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString: ConnectionString);
       CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
       CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName: AzureBlobContainer);

       await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

       BlobContainerPermissions blobContainerPermissions = await cloudBlobContainer.GetPermissionsAsync();
       blobContainerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;

       await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions: blobContainerPermissions);

       CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName: blobName);
       cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";

       using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer: data))
       {
           await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(source: stream);
       }

       return cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
   }
   ```

Here are the resources I'm reading somehow related to this issue IMO, but are not helping much:

[Investigating ASP.Net Memory Dumps for Idiots (like Me)](https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2014/03/20/investigating-aspnet-memory-dumps-for-idiots-like-me)

[ASP.NET app eating memory. Application / Session objects the reason?](https://serverfault.com/questions/302510/asp-net-app-eating-memory-application-session-objects-the-reason)

[IIS Worker Process using a LOT of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245727/iis-worker-process-using-a-lot-of-memory)

[Run dispose method upon asp.net IIS app restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671485/run-dispose-method-upon-asp-net-iis-app-restart)

[IIS: Idle Timeout vs Recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985710/iis-idle-timeout-vs-recycle)

UPDATE:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path: LocalImageFilePath))
{
    string BlobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(format: "n");
    string ImageURL = string.Empty;

    using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(LocalImageFilePath, FileMode.Open)
    {
        ImageURL = await CreateBlob(blobName: $"{BlobName}.png", dataStream: fileStream);
    }

    System.IO.File.Delete(path: LocalImageFilePath);

    oJSON = new { url = ImageURL };
}
```

Comment: The only thing that can cause memory usage to go up is in `CreateBlob()`, which isn't shown. **You** need to analyze your code and memory usage, that's not something we can easily do. Starting a process does not cause the starting process's memory to go up, so that part of your question is a red herring.

Comment: I updated the question with the CreatBlob method

Comment: I mean that everytime I call the API (and it executes the wkhtmltoimage.exe) ~120mb of RAM are added to this IIS Worker Process and I expect when the exe conlcudes this RAM to be released by the IIS Worker Process, but it's not (at least not immediately) and it adds up every time

Comment: This can also be a problem. (More so if the file is large) `byte[] pngBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path: LocalImageFilePath);` If this happens occasionaly, the process might receive an increasing amount of memory  -even though it might not be in use-. As the others have said: Profile your app.

Comment: @mjwills, I use the UploadFromStreamAsync because this is the example I found initially (is this relevant to the problem?), the IIS process consumes the RAM, not wkhtmltoimage.exe. The latter only consumes a little CPU while executing, then calms down quickly when it finishes its job as seen in the Task Manager

Comment: Depending on the size of some of the objects being allocated, you _may_ be advised to set `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode` to `CompactOnce` at the end of your method. Generally it is best to stay out of the GC's way - but if profiling shows this method is allocating objects large enough to be in the Large Object Heap then setting that may give it some hints to clean itself up a little earlier.

Comment: Does performance improve if you use a `FileStream` and pass that to `UploadFromStreamAsync` instead? Note this will require changing the `byte[]` parameter of `CreateBlob` to be a stream instead, and stopping using `ReadAllBytes`.

Comment: You might consider offloading all that work, it is IMO not really appropriate for a request/response cycle anyway. You should be able to know the image url without waiting for the process to run so I would drop a message on a queue and have your process run in an Azure function or similar.

Comment: @mjwillis Yes, I changed the "System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes" inside the Index AR to "using Stream fileStream = new FileStream(LocalImageFilePath, FileMode.Open))" and pass the fileStream to CreateBlob method, leaving the UploadFromStreamAsync call and I think the RAM is OK right now. The crazy adding up of ~100mb everytime is reduced significantly IMO. It once again inevitably adds more RAM but very little compared to what was before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of your pain is the allocation of large byte arrays:

```
byte[] pngBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path: LocalImageFilePath);
```

The easiest change to make, to try and encourage the GC to collect the Large Object Heap more often, is to set `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode` to `CompactOnce` at the end of the method. That *might* help.

But, a better idea would be to remove the need for the large array altogether. To do this, change:

```
private async Task<string> CreateBlob(string blobName, byte[] data)
```

to instead be:

```
private async Task<string> CreateBlob(string blobName, FileStream data)
```

And then later use:

```
await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(source: data);
```

In the caller, you'll need to stop using `ReadAllBytes`, and instead use a `FileStream` to read the file instead.